# how to do a HTTP post to a web service?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, http, post

I need to do a HTTP post to a web service..

If I place this into a web browser like this

```
http://server/ilwebservice.asmx/PlaceGPSCords?userid=99&longitude=-25.258&latitude=25.2548
```

then is stores the values to our DB on the server..

In Eclipse, using Java programming for android.. The url will look like

```
http://server/ilwebservice.asmx/PlaceGPSCords?userid="+uid+"&longitude="+lng1+"&latitude="+lat1+"
```

with `uid`, `lng1` and `lat1` being assigned as strings..

How would I run this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how you would execute that URL from java code instead of thru a browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String getURL = "http://server/ilwebservice.asmx/PlaceGPSCords?userid="+uid+"&longitude="+lng1+"&latitude="+lat1+";
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                //do something with the response
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is a GET, not a POST

Answer (score 2):

For http post use name value pair. See below code -

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", long1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat1));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 2):

Infact I had done already what you are going to do. So try this stff. You can create a method like this what I have and pass your URL with lat, long. This is return you the response of the `HTTP connection.`

```
public static int sendData(String url) throws IOException
    {
        try{
            urlobj = new URL(url);
            conn = urlobj.openConnection();
            httpconn= (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpconn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpconn.setDoInput(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();}
        try{
            responseCode = httpconn.getResponseCode();}
        catch(Exception e){
            responseCode = -1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseCode;
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution as it is generic and re-usable.  Put the String url creation logic outside of the sendData() method.   However, to make the solution complete for all level of programmers the calling code might be useful showing the variables being set in the String that gets passed to the reusable sendData() method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if I did I think you can use java.net.UrlConnection :

```
URL url = new URL("http://server/ilwebservice.asmx/PlaceGPSCords?userid="+uid+"&longitude="+lng1+"&latitude="+lat1);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```